# Quick question on why two measures have equal total mass.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am following *Probability with Martingales* by Williams

[image]

I am having troubles with why the two measures $H \rightarrow P(I \cap H)$ and $H \rightarrow P(I)P(H)$ have the same total mass $P(I)$.

Is the total mass the $ \sum_i P(I \cap H_i)$ where $H_i$ are all the disjoint elements of $\mathcal{H}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A measure space is always a triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, where the set $\Omega$ is the set with respect to which $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra. The value of $\mu(\Omega)$ is called total mass of $\mu$. The measure $\mu$ is a probability measure iff its total mass is $1$.

Now observe that $P(I \cap \Omega) = P(I) = P(I) \cdot P(\Omega)$, so both measures have the same total mass $P(I)$.